# How can I update an existing JSON object's parameters in Grails?

Tags: json, angularjs, grails

I'm making a todo list. When first entering the item and adding it to the list, the server works great. It takes the parameters that the user selects and passes them into a list on the server that can be viewed by rendering Item.list(), that looks like so:

```
[{"class":"server.Item","id":1,"assignedTo":"User 1","comments":null,"completed":false,"creator":"User 1","name":"Task 1","priority":"1","type":"Personal"},
{"class":"server.Item","id":2,"assignedTo":"User 2","comments":null,"completed":false,"creator":"User 2","name":"Er","priority":"3","type":"Work"},
{"class":"server.Item","id":3,"assignedTo":"User 1","comments":null,"completed":false,"creator":"User 2","name":"Ga","priority":"1","type":"Work"}]
```

Now, the user then has the option to edit the task later. On the client side this works fine, but then I need the user to be able to save the new, updated task.

This is my current update function:

```
def updateList() {
    def newItem = Item.findById(request.JSON.id)

    newItem.assignedTo = request.JSON.assignedTo
    newItem.comments = request.JSON.comments
    newItem.completed = request.JSON.completed
    newItem.creator = request.JSON.creator
    newItem.name = request.JSON.name
    newItem.priority = request.JSON.priority
    newItem.type = request.JSON.type
    newItem.save(flush: true)
    render newItem as JSON
}
```

This doesn't work, however. I get a null pointer exception that says "Cannot set property "assignedTo" on null object. I'm assuming that the findById request is not getting anything for the JSON object, and thus there is no object to assign values to, however I don't know what the problem is considering the items are in fact being put into the Item.list().

This is called with the following JS function on the client side:

```
$scope.updateList = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
       // serverList.save({command: 'updateList'}, item);
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/server/todoList/updateList', item)
            .success(function(response) {})
            .error(function(response) {alert("Failed to update");});
    });
};
```

Comment: Unrelated - avoid `findById` and use `get` instead. It won't affect this issue because it does basically the same thing, but they're cached very differently and `get` will perform much better.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on your Grails version, but you should be able to do this:

```
def update(Item item) {
  if (!item) {
    // return a 404
  } else {
    // you should really use a service and not save
    // in the controller
    itemService.update(item)
    respond item
  }
}
```

Grails is smart enough look that item up since there is an ID in the JSON params, and populate the object correctly.

Comment: If you don't mind, what would the itemService service look like?

Comment: most likely just `item.save()` unless you had more business logic to put around it. But using the service layer is the preferred practice. So it was just a suggestion.

Comment: Does initiating a post request pass the variable declared in update(Item item)? If not, how do I declare item?

Comment: Read the section called Data Binding and Action Arguments here: http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding

Answer (score 0):

Sort of a work around for anyone else that may need to do this in a basic manner, what I've done that works is clear the list when "Update List" is clicked, then read back in the values that are currently in the client side list.

Grails:

```
def clearList() {
    Item.executeUpdate('delete from Item')
    render Item.list()
}

def updateList() {
    def newItem = new Item(request.JSON)
    newItem.save(flush:true)
    render newItem as JSON
}
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.updateList = function() {    // Update list on the server
    serverList.get({command: 'clearList'});
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
        serverList.save({command: 'updateList'}, item);
    });
};
```